# AoE: Castle Siege - Which buildings get hidden during an attack?

Tags: age-of-empires-castle-siege

One of the most important things to consider when playing Castle Siege is the resources you'll spend on defences. Additionally, this means you'll have to carefully place walls and fortifications to defend all important buildings. However, I have noticed that when a player attacks you, some buildings are not visible to them (e.g. the army camps). Considering that they do not see them, it is useless to protect them and waste precious wall hubs on them.

Therefore I was wondering which buildings are visible to an attacker and which aren't. The ones that aren't can then be put far away in a corner.

I am guessing that the following buildings are hidden, but I am not sure:

- Army camps only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only army camps.  Just dump them in the corner of your map (well out of the way of your castle/walls).

Traps are of course hidden, everything else is freely available for the attacker to destroy.

You can check for yourself by comparing your castle to a replay of a recent defense.  You should see the army camps marked out but the buildings do not appear.  Everything else should be visible.